# How can I add a drag icon to a table to make it sortable with jQuery UI sortable?

Tags: jquery

I use the following to allow me to sort rows in a table.

```
$('#grid tbody').sortable({      
        helper: function (e, ui) {  
            ui.children().each(function () {  
                $(this).width($(this).width());  
            });  
            return ui;  
        },  
        scroll: true,  
        stop: function (event, ui) {  
            //                   
        }  
    }).disableSelection();
```

But the problem is now I can't make changes to the table. Here's an example.

Note that this is just an example. My real table has input fields so the user can enter input data. This is the reason that I can't just use disableSelection.

```
<table id="grid" >
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>A</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>B</td><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>C</td><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>D</td><td>4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>E</td><td>5</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Does anyone know how I can make it so an up/down arrow appears for me to use as a drag handle for sorting? Hopefully using the jQuery UI icons.

Comment: are you importing ui.css?? pretty sure it should add it by default

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#grid tbody').sortable({      
        helper: function (e, ui) {  
            ui.children().each(function () {  
                $(this).width($(this).width());  
            });  
            return ui;  
        },  
        scroll: true,  
        handle : '.handle',
        stop: function (event, ui) {  
            //                   
        }  
    }).disableSelection();
```

Comment: this will add the hand icon, is this what you need?